# where can i find a list of the actions that i put in the intent filter (receiver) inside the manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, action, intentfilter

I'm looking for a full list of intent filters actions - such as:

```
<receiver android:name=".BTDetector">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

stuff like the "**android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED**". I can't find it in the documentation anywhere! If there isn't a comprehensive list somewhere(and why there wouldn't be is beyond me), I'm looking for the action for the intent filter for Bluetooth discovery start. since i'm running this in a service, I can't (and don't want to) do it dynamically...

Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BluetoothAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) and [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

As for *all* Android intent actions, the docs for `Intent` contain most. Other things such as Bluetooth etc are usually defined in the various packages that provide that functionality.

Comment: perhaps i'm misreading both of those, but they don't contain the actual intent i.e. android.intent.action.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY (I just made that one up, but i'm looking for something like that). they only have "android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND", which won't work if i put it in to the intent filter list....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do. Quoting from your original question..."I'm looking for the action for the intent filter for Bluetooth discovery start."...`BluetoothAdapter` has the following...`ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` which would be `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED` if used in the manifest intent filter.

Comment: ok, I figured out what my "problem" was - I was under the impression that in order for me to listen to an intent, it should have the word "intent" in the string (android.intent.action....). after playing with my code, I see that's not the case. thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. As you've obviously worked out, `android.intent...` is just a unique namespace used as a prefix for the most common intent actions and extras. As new functionality and packages are added to Android, the 'namespace' prefix will vary. If you ever create your own intent actions, use the `com.mycompany.mypackage.ACTION_MY_ACTION` approach.

Answer (score 0):

see this full list of intents in android   [Intent.java](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/ag-gb-dsds-7227/repository/revisions/18065ea37751cc6fc3a07430b22f469df8d29339/entry/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java)